# Can WiX do anything besides RollBack and Log files if installer fails? Like reboot?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, custom-action, bootstrapper, failed-installation

I have an installer whose initial installation will be done by a human, but updates have to be done automagically.

Handling installer failure is a problem.  I have to plan for the installer to fail:  I use the <[RollbackBoundary](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/rollbackboundary.html)/> element in the Bootstrapper to get to a good state, and then I use both the WiX log and a log of my own devising to document the failure.

However, that's not good enough.

There's a program (let's call it **X.exe**).  If-and-when the installer fails, I need to roll back to the state that the installer was in before the installer started and:

- Restart **X.exe** or
- Restart the target machine so that **X.exe** can start (I install **X.exe** into the startup folder of the target computer; this is also what I do for a successful install -- restart the target machine).
- Deal with the problem in some as-yet unforeseen way.

Is there anything besides Logging that WiX can do for a installer failure?  Is there a condition that is set that I could catch, or... anything?

I learned WiX through the fantastic book [WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782160426) (by Nick Ramirez), but I can't find anything to solve my problem there, nor can I find it on the interwebs.

I'm hoping there's something obvious I missed.  Does anyone know how to deal with installer failure besides logging them and calling it a day?

---

Based on the lack of answers and lack of finding the answer to my question in existing resources, I realize that I'm simply asking Windows Installer to do too much.

I was hoping that there would be a way to do something like:

```
if (installation fails)
{
    do something (besides rollback and logging)
}
```

I wonder if other installation programs provide functionality like this?  Or if there's some other way to get a target machine to do something if the installer fails?

Comment: MSI installs are transactional - they completely work or completely fail, so your comment " If-and-when the installer fails, I need to either roll back to the state that the installer was in before the installer started " doesn't apply. The machine will be in the state it was prior to the install, subject to custom actions having rollback actions etc. MSI installs also use system restore to snapshot the system.

Comment: Ah, it's the "either" in the comment.  It makes the entire sentence not make sense.  I'll take that out....

Comment: The sentence makes much more sense now -- I realize that MSIs are transactional.  I want to do something if the MSI fails.

Answer (score 0):

There is, in theory, but the whole area of rollback is fraught with caveats. Consider the "installation failed" dialog box and how it differs from a success case: you could run a custom action on that dialog box. But that's only if there's UI. So maybe do things from the rollback action. But what if [Rollbacks are disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368307)? Your only mildly robust solution will be outside of the Windows Installer package.

So in your X.exe, make sure to capture the return code so you can identify a success, a cancelation, a failure, and various reboot required states. If it's a failure, then consider applying your external fix (your reboot, or whatever). If you didn't write X.exe, consider doing so, or writing something that will call X.exe.

But really PhilDW's comment gets to the core of it: rebooting on failure is not an expected behavior for an application installer. (Reboots by application installers in general are advised against.)